# Group Layer with dynamic vector layers

Tags: openlayers

Starting from the previous solution. Would it be possible to create a group with several dynamic vector layers? I tried to do it but it gives me an `AssertionError` when I create the group.

```
function search(){
    var element = document.getElementById("formName");
    obje = document.getElementById('cbx_esp');
    var txt='';
    txt = "\""+obje.value+"\"";
    url_obje = 'abundance='+txt;
    drawAbundance(obje.value);
}

var vectorlayer;

function drawAbundance(cbx_espId){
    var vectorAbundance = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new  ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            var proj = projection.getCode();
            var url = "obAbundance.php"
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var params = {
                abundance: cbx_espId
            }

            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var onError = function() {
               vectorAbundance.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            }
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = function() {
                xhr.responseText;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    vectorAbundance.addFeatures(
                        vectorAbundance.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                    );
                    map.getView().fit(vectorAbundance.getExtent());
                    $("#formName")[0].reset();
               } else {
                 onError();
               }
             }
             xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        },
    });
    vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source:vectorAbundance,
        visible:true,
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
        style: distICES,                
    });

    //map.addLayer(vectorlayer)
}

//A second query and function to make a vectorlayer2 I don't write it
...
//Group Layer abundance
var abundance = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers:[vectorlayer, vectorlayer2],
    visible:false,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});
map.addLayer(abundance);
```

If I add the vector layer in the `drawAbundance` function (and the other one) and then add them to the group layer, it gives me the `AssertionError 58`. If I don't add it in the function, and once I make the group I add the group to the map, too gives me the `AssertionError 58`.

Comment: A layer can be used only in one place.  If it is added to the map as part of a group it cannot be added again (or in another group).  But layer sources can be shared between layers, if you need the same data in two places.

Comment: But if I don't add the layer in the drawAbundance and drawAbundance2 function, I'm not actually adding them, right? I mean, if I remove map.addLayer (vectorlayer) and map.addLayer (vectorlayer2) from the functions, I'm not adding them at the moment, or am I wrong?
I thought doing the group afterwards and doing map.addLayer (abundance); it would work.

Comment: If either of `vectorlayer` or `vectorlayer2` have already been added you cannot add `abundance` if it also contains those layers.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What I am saying is that having commented on the line in which I add vectorlayer1 and vectorlayer2 in each of the functions, I do it when I create the abundance group as I put in the example: var abundance = new ol.layer.Group ({...
it keeps giving me the AssertionError58

Comment: You declare the function `drawAbundance` but do you run it before creating the layer group?  If not you are creating a group using a array with two undefined values.

Comment: I'm doing the query and I'm adding the features to the vector, but I'm not adding it to the map. Outside of the function I am declaring the layer group and adding the group to the map. maybe I'm misunderstanding how it's done. I can't add each vector layer before creating the group, and if I add them later to the group layer it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way I created the vector layer, not how I did the group layer. @Mike helped me with this issue.
the vector layer is created without source, to later add the source with the features.

```
vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    visible:true,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    style: style,
    maxZoom:9,          
});

function drawAbunda(cbx_espId){
    var vectorAbundance = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new  ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            var proj = projection.getCode();
            var url = "Abundance.php"
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var params = {
                abunda: cbx_espId
            }
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var onError = function() {
               vectorAbundance.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            }
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = function() {
                xhr.responseText;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    vectorAbundance.addFeatures(
                        vectorAbundance.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                    );
                    //map.getView().fit(vectorAbundance.getExtent());
                    $("#formEsp")[0].reset();
                    $("#abundance").show();
               } else {
                 onError();
               }
             }
             xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        },
    });
    vectorlayer.setSource(vectorAbundance);
}
```

The second function to vectorlayer2 (I don't write the function), and I make the group layer with the two layers.

```
var abundance = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers:[vectorlayer, vectorlayer2],
    visible:true,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});
```

and I add the group layer to the map, I am adding it in an array of layers.

```
var layers = [osm, layer1, layer2, layer3, ... , abundance];
```